# javascript text field focus disable block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make two text field as follows

```
<input id="email" class="email" value = "${user.email}" />
<input id="password" class="password" display="none" />
```

I'd like to change my email with current password. So I want to make password text field (its default display is none) to be activated, when I try to type in email text field to change email address.

To to this, I use javascript code. How can I make a code for this? 
Should I use focus() or live() for this? Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: use javascript on keyup()

Comment: So when some one goes to change the password it changes their email address?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#email').keyup(function() {  
    $('#password').show();
}
```